# TKinter Combobox font size

Tags: python, combobox, tkinter

```
self.box_value = StringVar()
    self.box = ttk.Combobox(stepFour, textvariable=self.box_value,width=40, font=('Fixed', 10))
    self.box.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>")
    self.box['values'] = ERROR_TYPES.keys()
    self.box.current(0)
    self.box.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=2)

ERROR_TYPES = {
"A": "Error Type A",
"B": "Error Type B",
"C": "Error Type C",
"D": "Error Type D",
 }
```

I have the above combobox, The box shows default item at font 10 like it shows, however when I expand the combobox list(clicking down arrow), the items seem to have the default font. Any ideas why items not taking the specified font?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide more code? And where does the error/unwanted behaviour happen?

Comment: No errors. No other code to go with this, just a combo box that is showing the list items with an unwanted font size. How do I set font size for all items in the list?

Comment: Answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43086378/how-to-modify-ttk-combobox-fonts) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938758/combobox-fontsize-in-tkinter). Pretty disappointing if you ask me as it's only applicable in certain cases, but better something than nothing.