# How to change the color of the active background of the dropdown menu (i.e. tk.Listbox) in a ttk.Combobox

Tags: python, tkinter

The following code creates a ttk.Combobox widget:

```
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
default_values = ['Peter','Scotty','Walter','Scott','Mary','Sarah','Jane',
                  'Oscar','Walley','Faith','Bill','Egor','Heley']
s=ttk.Style()
s.configure( 'TCombobox', font=('Purisa', 20, 'bold'), background ='cyan',
             fieldbackground='pink')
c=ttk.Combobox(values=default_values)
c.master.option_add( '*TCombobox*Listbox.background', 'yellow')
c.master.option_add( '*TCombobox*Listbox.selectbackground','red') #does not work
c.master.option_add( '*TCombobox*Listbox.selectforeground','grey') #does not work  
c.master.option_add( '*TCombobox*Listbox.highlightbackground','blue') # does not work
c.master.option_add( '*TCombobox*Listbox.highlightforeground','green') #does not work
c.master.option_add( '*TCombobox*Listbox.activestyle', 'underline') #does not work
c.grid()
```

After clicking on the Combobox downarrow, a dropdown menu (which is a `tk.Listbox` widget) containing the `default values` will appear. When the mouse hovers over the dropdown menu, an active background below the mouse pointer will appear. **I would like to change the color of this grey active background. How do I do so?**

As the [dropdown menu isn't a ttk widget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28940421/5722359), it will not respond to and `ttk.Style()` settings. I have also tried the `.option_add` method but only the Listbox background could be changed.

Issue:
[image: active background in dropdown menu]

Comment: I doesn't see any grey active background. Can you provide a screenshot? This will be more better.

Comment: @BlackThunder I can't do a screenshot. Whenever the drop-down menu appears, screenshot function becomes inactive/deactivated. Had to snap a shot of the widget issue with a mobile. You can see the grey background behind the mouse pointer; it follows the mouse pointer. Can share an image of the widget at your end?

Comment: So its grey for you. Its blue for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the correct option to make the background color change:

```
c.master.option_add( '*TCombobox*Listbox.selectbackground','red')
```

But you made a little mistake i.e. `selectbackground`. In `selectbackground` , the first letter of `background` should be capital.
`*TCombobox*Listbox.selectbackground` becomes `*TCombobox*Listbox.selectBackground`
`-----------------------__^__-----------------------------------------__^__-------`

Try:

```
c.master.option_add( '*TCombobox*Listbox.selectBackground','red')
```

Similarly , `foreground` becomes `Foreground`.

Comment: Thank you. Spot on... :) May I know the documentation detailing the correct syntax? The new mexico tech documentation did not show the capital letter.

Comment: @SunBear I surprised that why is it not working so I checked the code carefully and found the problem. However got some help from https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/listbox.htm

Comment: @SunBear I also noticed that somewhere it is capital and somewhere lower. So I experimented with capital.

Comment: According to the tcl documentation, not using capital letter should also work. Still, I guess this is one of nuances of tkinter to live with until the package developer resolve it.